# Can the vertical spacing be removed in this css layout by any modern means?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: current layout]

I'm trying to achieve the Pinterest layout with entities of variable width and height. So not only the height is variable in the given layout.

The layout from above is achieved with flexbox (row wrap) on the parent. I would like to move column 31 to be right under column 1, instead of where it is right now, and column 32 to be right under column 2, and so on. I think it has something to do with the cross-axis property of flexbox, but I could not find the right property.

This is a node webkit prototype, so if it works in webkit, then this is great. Any ideas?

Another idea that I am considering is using a css grid, but I have to define a finite number of grid rows and columns, while this layout should be flexible, so making the window wider should increase the number of columns.

Comment: So you are looking for something like this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html ?

Comment: Yes, that is right, but with CSS only.

Comment: With css only is not possible. That is if you want it to be dynamic. The only way is to make each column in separate div, but once resize everything will go to hell... Or you can make the columns fluid, but it won't be practical.

Comment: [Here](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/creating-css-pinterest-style-masonry-layout/) is a CSS-only solution, but it has a lot of issues as pointed out in the post. A popular solution that doesn't require jQuery (uses pure JavaScript) is [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Filly, but doesn't that css layout use only two columns?

Comment: I don't think so, in my version of Chrome at least it displays this way: http://i.imgur.com/16BZa5a.png. Maybe you're seeing it differently because of the cross-browser issues it mentions.